# SpringSecurity - SecurityConfiguration.java - HttpSecurity - not working

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I am trying to implement Spring Security to my MVC Maven based project with already included Spring Boot.

I have working front-end and back-end but until now I was using fake login - I was simply scoping user data such as username and password via JS and AngularJS and sending it to the back-end controller where data from DB was retrieved via DAO layer and compared to the scoped info after witch response was sent - and if it was "OK" I forwarded user to the User Home Page and vice versa.
This means that if I run my app and type directly to the browser bar **localhost:8080/#/user** (page that only user that is loged in is supposed to see) I can access it without any problems.

Now when business logic layer testing is finished the time has come to implement Spring Security.

I am still trying to understand Spring Security and trying to properly write SecurityConfiguration.java file - to have it set so it wont let no one access book.html and user.html pages, and, eventually, redirect such user to login.html.

This is my SecurityConfiguration.java file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Resource
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder PasseordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        JdbcUserDetailsManager userDetailsService = new JdbcUserDetailsManager();
        userDetailsService.setDataSource(dataSource);
        PasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();

        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(encoder);
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource);

        if (!userDetailsService.userExists("user")) {
            List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER"));
            User userDetails = new User("user", encoder.encode("password"),
                    authorities);

            userDetailsService.createUser(userDetails);
        }

    }

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/user").access("hasRole('USER')")
                .antMatchers("/book").access("hasRole('USER')");
    }

}
```

But when I run the app and try to access for example /user it allows me to! Can someone help me understand what am I to do, and how to fix this and pass the first step?

Comment: Are you sure that this file is processed by Spring ? Have you any message from Spring security in your logs at INFO level ?

Comment: I have no checked the logging (not used it until now) but if I change configure method body to `http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated().and().formLogin().loginPage("collections/login");` - I get **This webpage has a redirect loop** on localhost:8080

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to declare an entry point for authentication. As you noted in your comment, you need to add `.and().formLogin().loginPa‌​ge("collections/login")` to your `http.authorizeRequests()`.

But, you also need to authorize unauthenticated access to the login page to avoid the redirect loop : ask page -> need authentication -> redirect to login page -> need authentication -> redirect ...

You should simply have followed the following example of the reference manual about *Java Configuration and Form Login* :

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login") 
            .permitAll();        
}
```

With your code, it gives :

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/user").access("hasRole('USER')")
        .antMatchers("/book").access("hasRole('USER')")
        .and().formLogin().loginPage("/collections/login").permitAll();
}
```

Last remark : note the **`/`** in front of login URL. **Always use absolute path** if you want your login page to be found from any page other than `/` !

Comment: This helped me understand how concept works and see that Spring Security is working on my App. Now I have more problems but I will have to post new question later on because my App is using AngularJS state provider and I do not know how to make it work without using absolute paths...

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go

Current

```
http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/user").access("hasRole('USER')")
                .antMatchers("/book").access("hasRole('USER')");
```

Change to:

```
http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/user").hasRole('USER')
                .antMatchers("/book").hasRole('USER');
```

Hope that helps (worked for me).